# Get and modify the control in the ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I am working with xaml and ControlTemplate as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}" x:Key="MyControlTemplate">

    <Grid Background="Transparent" Name="DisplayGrid"  >


        <local:MyDisplay x:Name="DisplayInstance" />
        <ContentPresenter   />


     </Grid>

</ControlTemplate>
```

Code:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{

    ....
    ....
    ....
    public MyControl()
    {
         Template = (ControlTemplate)Resources["MyControlTemplate"];

         MyDisplay display = Template.FindName("DisplayInstance", this);
         // It return null
    }


}
```

I would like to get and set the "DisplayInstance" in the Template.
I tried the official method (using Template.FindName(string, FrameworkElement)) but it always return null.

So, how should I do to get and modify the "DisplayInstance" and any other control in the ControlTemplate/Xaml? So that the content of the ControlTemplate will change during runtime.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom control override the [OnApplyTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate.aspx) method and place your code that is dependent on the named controls in there. eg try:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        MyDisplay display = Template.FindName("DisplayInstance", this); 
    }
```